# How to get windows client username in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, windows, express

I am developing a little application in nodeJS and AngularJS. all my clients are windows machines, and they are all in the same domain.
From angularjs calling node api to get client username

I tried node-sspi & os package, but it asks for windows authentication.

How can we get client username without windows authentication?

Comment: Please check this https://nodejs.org/api/os.html you are able to all access system information.

Comment: It returns servers username where nodejs app is hosted

Comment: This kind of info is not available in headers. You would need to send it from the browser. Not sure if its possible to get the windows username at browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **os** node.js package to get username:

```
const os = require('os');
const {username} = os.userInfo();
```

Comment: It returns servers username where nodejs app is hosted.

Comment: Of course, it will return the name of the host user. It's impossible to get windows user name from a browser.

Comment: You asked "how to get in node.js" here the answer. of course you can't get that username if you are not hosting app on some certain machine